# sqlSave in the RODBC writes line by line in the database

Tags: r, oracle11g, rodbc

I am writing 250K rows with 6 columns (1 string, 2 Dates, 3 double) in a Oracle database via the function sqlSave in the package RODBC.
The database is an Oracle 11, the Driver for the odbc Connection is the 11.02.00.03
Here is my code:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("mydb", uid="id", pwd="pwd")
sqlSave(ch, myRobject, tablename = "myTable", safer=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, nastring = NULL, fast = TRUE)
```

myRobject does not have a key. myTable has an index over one of the date columns.
sqlSave takes circa 15 minutes to write the dataframe into myTable. I tried to execute the same task with the sqlLoader with data in a .csv file and this is much faster (it takes circa 8 sec.). I am aware that it is expected that the sqlLoader would be faster. However the time difference still strikes me.

I have to add that even if I set the option

> fast=TRUE

I see that sqlSave writes the data in the database one at the time. According to the RODBC documentation it should instead try to write the dataframe as a block

> fast = ... If true, use a parametrized INSERT INTO or UPDATE query to
>   write all the data in one operation.

Is it a database issue? or instead an R/ODBC one?
Any idea how to improve the speed would be very appreciated.

Comment: Give a try to `ROracle` package.